# Coffeescript $.ajax result shown as undefind

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I work with a front-end framework and want to render a page. To do that I use an initializer that calls a function performing $.ajax call to the backend. However, though in chrome dev tools the request is successful, everytime I do console.log it returns undefined. The backend sends the right result but it's not shown.

```
  initialize: =>
    @build_recent()
    @payload=@recent_data
    console.log(@payload)

  render: =>
    $(@el).append homeTemplate(@payload)
    @

  build_recent: =>
    $.ajax(
      url: '/build_recent'
      dataType: 'text/json'
      type: 'GET'
      success: (data) =>
        @recent_data = data
    )
```

Update:

simply only using render() not using intialize and another function, I finally solved the problem this way:

```
  render: =>
    $.ajax(
      url: '/build_recent/'
      dataType: 'json'
      type: 'GET'
      success: (data) =>
        @payload = data
        $(@el).append homeTemplate(@payload)
        return @
    )
```

it turns out that the problem was only this `dataType: 'json'` previously I use `dataType: 'text/json'`

now it works out fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your coffeescript renders to:

```
var _this = this;

({
  initialize: function() {
    _this.build_recent();
    _this.payload = _this.recent_data;
    return console.log(_this.payload);
  },
  render: function() {
    $(_this.el).append(homeTemplate(_this.payload));
    return _this;
  },
  build_recent: function() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/build_recent',
      dataType: 'text/json',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        return _this.recent_data = data;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And **you cannot** return from an ajax statement. you must use a callback!

So your rendered js code can be changed to:

```
({
  initialize: function() {
    _this.build_recent();
    //moved into callback
  },
  render: function() {
    $(_this.el).append(homeTemplate(_this.payload));
    return _this;
  },
  build_recent: function() {
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/build_recent',
      dataType: 'text/json',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        _this.recent_data = data;
        //in callback
        _this.payload = _this.recent_data;
        console.log(_this.payload);
        //prob want to render:
        _this.render();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: actually you can manage to return directly a value if you set async = false in the ajax options (but it'll freeze the page so I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: Right, this is an async problem. If you want `build_recent` to just make the Ajax call, and you want to do something after that call, then `build_recent` needs to take a callback.

Comment: @Neal I tried it but it still returns an undefined in the console

Comment: @Neal I finally solved it using callbacks as you suggested and also making it simple